# how to validate multiple file upload field editing the "validateBread" method in the default Voyager BREAD controller

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I'm overwriting the default Voyager BREAD Controller. I copied the `VoyagerBreadController.php` file in `app\Http\Controllers\VoyagerMoviesController.php` and I modified the `validateBread` method as below. It almost works; it validates correctly other sort of field, but it doesn'work properly for upload file field (which we know is a multiple file upload field). The field name is "nomefile". I suspect a syntax error in my code, could you please help me?

```
 public function validateBread($request, $data, $name = null, $id = null) {

    //Start my modification
    //dd($request);

    $rules  = [
        'sottotitolo' => 'required',
        'nomefile.*' => 'mimes:jpg,png'  //this is what won't work
    ];

    $messages  = [
        'sottotitolo.required' => '... we need this value, please.'
    ];

    //end of my modification

    //$rules = []; of course these two lines were uncommented
    //$messages = [];
    $customAttributes = [];
    $is_update = $name && $id;

    $fieldsWithValidationRules = $this->getFieldsWithValidationRules($data);

    foreach ($fieldsWithValidationRules as $field) {
        $fieldRules = $field->details->validation->rule;
        $fieldName = $field->field;
```

Answer (score 0):

`jpg` is not a valid mimetype.
Instead use `jpeg`.
See https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types for all mimetypes.

Comment: $rules  = [
          'sottotitolo' => 'required',
          'nomefile.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,png'
      ]; //but it doesn't work. I click the submit and the page stays still.